# De Sqlite a MySql (varios registros a la vez)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Como poder hacer un select a los registros que he creado con mi método de "alta" (para ver que los guarda como quiero) mi problema es que quiero crear la tabla sin una PK, y también quería saber cual es la forma mas útil de subir los datos guardados en sqlite ya que la única forma que conozco es subir los registros de a uno y estos los saco de los TextView (Asyntask), resumiendo mis dudas
- ver registros de sqlite con  un listview o lo mas sencillo(solo comprobar datos)
- subir a mi tb idéntica en mysql con un asyntask los datos guardados en el sqlite (son varios ya que usare un handler para insertar a medida que cambia la ubicación del gps) // quizás con un array o un cursor y recorrerlo?

y por ultimo un consejo para poder hacer una buena sincronizacion de bd entre la local y la web.

Android studio 2.2.1 api23
La aplicación consta de los metodos getlatitude() y getlongitud() de la clase GetLocation para el gps y estas se guardan con un id + una fecha (4 campos) los cuales al tener conexión a Internet se subiran por segundo plano a mi webserver y se borraran los datos de la tabla (sqlite) para evitar que crezca mucho la base de datos al terminar de subirlos con el asyntask.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    private Cursor fila;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);



    }

    public void Cargar (View v) {

        //carga los datos ?¿

    }


    public void alta(View v) {
        //crea objeto "admin" con el nombre con la BD "gpss" , pass "null", Version Bd "1"(update +1)
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"gpsss", null, 1);
        //se crea un objeto  de base de datos "db" que posee el objeto anterior con permisos de escrituras
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        //extrae el texto de los editetext (4)
        String id = tv1.getText().toString();
        String latitud = tv2.getText().toString();
        String longitud = tv3.getText().toString();
        String fecha = tv4.getText().toString();
        //inicializa "registro" (tipo array hashmap)
        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues(); //es una clase para guardar datos para el intent
        //pasa los parametros por via intent a la tabla gps
        //tamhbine pasa el estr
        registro.put("id", id);
        registro.put("latitud", latitud);
        registro.put("longitud", longitud);
        registro.put("fecha", fecha);
        bd.insert("gps", null, registro);
        bd.close();
        //pone en blanco los edittext (4)
        //et1.setText("");
        //et2.setText("");
        //et3.setText("");
        //et4.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se cargaron los datos de la persona",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



    public void SubirWeb(View V) {
        //subir parametros cargados en textview
    }


    public void BorrarTabla (View v){

        //delete TABLA y crear otra con el mismo nombre
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry se corto la primera parte del texto donde decía "buenos días quería preguntyarles de forma muy amable"

Comment: La forma apropiada de hacer esa sincronizacion es haciendo un servicio(Backend as a service, sugerible normalmente un servicio Restful) que reciba los datos, y el gestione la conexion y la interaccion con la base de datos mysql, tambien alguna vez conecte directamente a android con servidor mysql externo usando un driver Jdbc algo viejo, funciona pero es lento ademas de consumir bastante bateria, de resto desde que se respeten los tipos de datos semejantes, ajeno a que hayan llaves o no la sincronizacion funciona, hay que tener en cuenta que sqlite no tiene los mismos tipos de datos que mysql,

Comment: escuche que con Json o firebase también se puede lograr la sincronizan de las bd remota y local ?¿?

Comment: @RobertoDaniel Firebase es un Baas y ofrece base de datos nosql

Comment: gracias por los comentario

Comment: Para eso necesitas crear un web service que reciba un ArrayList de objetos y que los inserte en tu base de datos MySQL. En la parte Android te recomiendo que uses retrofit para conectar al webservice y enviar el Array con los datos.